# unidentified data in server response

Tags: javascript, rest, http

I'm trying to GET a file from an endpoint.

the reponse.data is like follows :

```
PK��foo.csv��Mj�@��=�v�L�B�l�ze,�)�ƌ4��M��9�b����@V�h��I����\�6��! G>�A�� ���2��b�q��!x��ع�&�f�    ���On�:U|*#j�M�A�w
%�T%��CPSl�\G`��J���so�ߧ�RlIĚ3uv”!��;h�
l%��>������ɓ�K�:�jGII���f�TZ�Y~�E`�i��t;��\�2tP��e��&��y:�;7���_�yE3G,�Ye��X���\k�T�<)�W���v�LES��-�� WO�PKu0A(�PK��PK(2017-10-16_Alertes_Statistiques_LISA.csv�UAn1�������\;p����`���Ů�R������~C?�K�ݸAHN�^�r8�p(z%�����%�7��9�%b0�<E�(@T�q���[���    
�[��C0��;��8"v���Iķf��/~}��>�>�o&�F��!G�6���r�n�
�D��,@c����h6(��2o�m��2F���9�_��
```

What type of content is that ?
Is that an octet stream ?
If so how can I convert it to an object I can download in the front end.

Comment: Please provide more information... What file is it? How is it being read? How is it being served? What the server-side is doing? Create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: can you show how you are accessing the data, might be encoding type issue

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a zip file. (Because it starts with 'P', 'K' bytes-characters, but it's not compulsory for zip standard). Just open and check what is inside (but it seems that's going to be CSV inside)